# How to proprely redirect in Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I create a new plugin (PalaisBDD) for my website in Wordpress but i got an issue :

First, i got 2 files :
PalaisBDD.php and Execution.php

In PalaisBDD.php i got this function :

```
function makeConnexion(){
  $link = plugins_url('Execution.php', __FILE__);
  $rendu = '';
  $rendu = "<form action='".$link."' method='POST'>
  <div>
    <label for='uti_login'>Login : </label>
    <input name='uti_login' id='uti_login' required autofocus>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for='uti_pwd'>Mot de passe :</label>
    <input type='password' name='uti_pwd' id='uti_pwd' required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type='submit' id='submitco' name='submitco' value='Connexion'> Connexion </button>
  </div>
  </form>";
  return $rendu;
}
```

I try this first in local with Wamp and redirection works well : PalaisBDD.php send data to Execution.php with the POST method and in Execution.php i get the data, verify login / password ... and redirect to the administration homepage with :

```
wp_redirect('https://mywebsite.fr/administration/');
```

but when i try this on my real website and i got the HTTP ERROR 500 on the page https://mywebsite.fr/wp-content/plugins/PalaisBDD/Execution.php

The all website work (just basic wordpress page) but when i click on the button submitco i go on the good page but with the HTTP ERROR 500

I apologize for my english and and thank you for your answers

Have a nice day !

Comment: On the web, always use forward slashes fin URLs. To your problem, [enable debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) to see the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem : the file Execution.php got a mistake ... Sorry for the topic and thank you Chris !